# Scala groupBy of a tuple to calculate stock basis

Tags: scala, tuples

I am working on an exercise to calculate stock basis given a list of stock purchases in the form of thruples (ticker, qty, stock_price).  I've got it working, but would like to do the calculation part in more of a functional way.  Anyone have an answer for this?

```
// input: 
// List(("TSLA", 20, 200),
//      ("TSLA", 20, 100),
//      ("FB", 10, 100)
// output:
// List(("FB", (10, 100)), 
//      ("TSLA", (40, 150))))

def generateBasis(trades: Iterable[(String, Int, Int)]) = { 
  val basises = trades groupBy(_._1) map {
    case (key, pairs) =>
      val quantity = pairs.map(_._2).toList
      val price = pairs.map(_._3).toList
      var totalPrice: Int = 0
      for (i <- quantity.indices) {
        totalPrice += quantity(i) * price(i)
      }
      key -> (quantity.sum, totalPrice / quantity.sum)
    }
  basises
}
```

Comment: did you your write this yourself? I mean, why doj't you ask whoever gave you this code what's the `Numeric` for?

Comment: I did write it myself but found from other examples that performing math operations on a set of elements from the tuple required the implicit numeric in there.  That really wasn't the main point of my questions and I will take it out.  I'd appreciate it if you retracted the downvote here as I'm just trying to wrap my head around this language.

Comment: @ScottManny cool. Did you also "find from other examples" _where_ that implicit was required? Like why did you use it around first occurrence of `quantity.sum`, but bot around the second one for example? What would happen if you did not use it the first time?

Comment: @Dima - I took out the implicit num and it worked just the same without it.  So that is just a completely unecessary distraction that I had in there and will take it out.  Thanks for questioning it.

Comment: I did not question "it". I questioned your idea to lift somebody's code without even understanding what it does, and throw it on SO pretending you "got it working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like this might work for you. (**updated**)

```
def generateBasis(trades: Iterable[(String, Int, Int)]) =
  trades.groupBy(_._1).mapValues {
    _.foldLeft((0,0)){case ((tq,tp),(_,q,p)) => (tq + q, tp + q * p)}
  }.map{case (k, (q,p)) => (k,q,p/q)}   // turn Map into tuples (triples)
```

Comment: The algorithm you have works for the test case I provided, however it doesn't work for other cost basis'.  The basis is weighted heavier when more stocks are purchased.  For example:
    Input:  
    `List(("TSLA", 20, 200), ("TSLA", 10, 100), ("FB", 10, 100)`
    Output:  

    `List(("FB", (10, 100)), ("TSLA", (30, 166)))`

Comment: Oops. Didn't fully appreciate the price calculations.  Try this updated attempt.

Comment: Way more concise than what I came up with.  I like the use of foldLeft.  Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution below.  Thanks everyone for their input.  I'd love to hear if anyone had a more elegant solution.

```
// input:
// List(("TSLA", 20, 200),
//      ("TSLA", 10, 100),
//      ("FB", 5, 50)
// output:
// List(("FB", (5, 50)),
//      ("TSLA", (30, 166)))
def generateBasis(trades: Iterable[(String, Int, Int)]) = {

  val groupedTrades = (trades groupBy(_._1)) map {
    case (key, pairs) =>
      key -> (pairs.map(e => (e._2, e._3)))
  } // List((FB,List((5,50))), (TSLA,List((20,200), (10,100))))

  val costBasises = for {groupedTrade <- groupedTrades

    tradeCost = for {tup <- groupedTrade._2 // (qty, cost)
    } yield tup._1 * tup._2 // (trade_qty * trade_cost)

    tradeQuantity = for { tup <- groupedTrade._2
    } yield tup._1 // trade_qty

  } yield (groupedTrade._1, tradeQuantity.sum, tradeCost.sum / tradeQuantity.sum )

  costBasises.toList // List(("FB", (5, 50)),("TSLA", (30, 166)))
}
```